# Finding specific users in archive event logs

Tags: windows, powershell, event-log

A situation has come up that we need to find the logon and logoff times of a specific user in are archived security event logs. For example I need to find out the date and times userX logged onto the system and then logged off.

This I what I have so far:

#

Update

#

This is what I have put together

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\security\* -Recurse |
ForEach-Object {
"Parsing $($_.FullName)`r`n"
try {
  Get-WinEvent userid=userX -FilterHashtable @{
    logname   = 'security'
    id        = 4624, 4634
    userid    = userX
    Path      = $_.FullName
    Level     = 2
    StartTime = "4/1/16"
    EndTime   = "6/20/2016"
  } -EA Stop
} catch [System.Exception] {
  "No errors in current log"
 }
}
```

I am confused on what you suggested to take out.  Also when I run this, it provides no results when I know it should be in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of [`Get-WinEvent`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849682.aspx) is wrong, but your exception handling is hiding the actual error this causes (because you interpret all exceptions as "no errors in current log"). First of all, the cmdlet doesn't accept `userid=userX` as a parameter, so remove it. All your filtering criteria should be in the hashtable. Also, the values in that hashtable need to be of the correct type.

> ### -FilterHashtable<Hashtable[]>
>
> […]
>
> The valid key-value pairs are as follows:
>
> - LogName=<String[]>
> - ProviderName=<String[]>
> - Path=<String[]>
> - Keywords=<Long[]>
> - ID=<Int32[]>
> - Level=<Int32[]>
> - StartTime=<DateTime>
> - EndTime=<DataTime>
> - UserID=<SID>
> - Data=<String[]>
> - *=<String[]>

For instance, `StartTime` and `EndTime` must be actual `DateTime` values. `ID` is the event ID (or list of event IDs) you're looking for. In your case it's probably the events 4624 and 4634 (see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/977519) for a complete list of relevant event IDs).

Finally remove the `try..catch`. You don't need it, since the error you get when no match is found is not a terminating error. If you want to suppress the error message simply redirect the Error output stream (`2>$null`).

Change the `Get-WinEvent` call to something like this and it should work:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
  LogName   = 'Security'
  ID        = 4624, 4634
  UserID    = 'userX'
  Path      = $_.FullName
  Level     = 2
  StartTime = [DateTime]'6/16/2016'
  EndTime   = [DateTime]'6/17/2016'
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help, I need to change that it just goes and looks in the different files in C:\A\B\C this is looking in my entire C: directory. What do I need to change so that it looks only in that folder looking at only the vent logs?  Also, it seems its pulling several other provider names